# hql: inner join with Map<key,value> and access key and value in select?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, dictionary, hql, inner-join

Here is problem

```
    public class Company
    {
            private Map<Location, Manager> locationManagerMap;
    }
```

A location has only one manager. A manager can be associated to many locations.

```
    public class Assignment
    {
            private Location location;
            private Manager
    }
```

Now suppose i want to retrieve list of all of assignments  for a company by using hql query with subquery some thing like as below.

```
    String query = "select from Assignment as assignment where (assignment.location, assignment.manager) in (select locationManager._____________ from Company as company inner join  company.locationManagerMap as locationManager where company.id=?) "
```

In subquery of query above, company is inner joined with locationManagerMap. I want to access key and value of this map to perform multiple column condition check. Please suggest what should be syntax in blanks in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
... index(locationManager), locationManager ...
```

Comment: In hibernate manual, wherever index function is referred it is used  for List. index() function return location of element in list like 1,2,3,... I doubt if we if index() will return key in case collection Map. Can u please give me reference to verify or have u verified it yourself.

Comment: @Maddy: When I checked it out, it returned map keys too.